# Deploy and secure microservices communication - best practices

Tags: node.js, microservices, nestjs

I have 2 microservices each connected to a db and two APIs and I was asking myself what are the best practices about deploying them in production.

Firstly, I thought about putting all the code on the same server. Each microservice will be in a docker container and same with the APIs. I will not use docker for databases(Mongo and MariaDB), instead they will be installed directly on the server. Only the port of the APIs will be opened and they will communicate with the microservices via TCP. 
Secondly I was wondering how can I secure the microservices or if is needed. The validation logic will be only on the APIs.

Thank you!

Comment: I suugest you use a message broker like rabbitmq for communication.

Comment: @rudreshsolanki Can you say why? What are the advantages, I only have 2 microservices?

Comment: It depends on where you want to host them . e.g. if you are using any cloud provider or on-prem ? If you want to deploy on containers are you planning to use any container orchestration like AWS ECS, Kubernetes etc ?

Comment: I said I will host them on the same server (simple vps from digital ocean). I will use docker, but no orchestrations.

Answer (score 0):

Some food for thoughts:

- Deploy several replicas of the same container to increase reliability and resilience. To manage load balancing and replicas you could use for instance kubernetes
- If your containers communicate between each other, you could think about enabling mTLS.
- Expose only the needed ports.
- If you deploy them in your own server pay attention to the maintenance of the underlying operating system.